# PS3 Symbols next to the WiFi symbol

Tags: ps3

This is my PS3. What is the cylinder on the left next to the WiFi symbol?

[image: PS3 Photo]

Is it something important or not?

Comment: You're going to get a much better reception if you do some initial research before asking us.  You can see that your latest questions are being downvoted for being rather trivial to answer.

Comment: I did research it on the internet but I couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 1):

That is the drive-activity indicator.

It is shown on [page 4 of the manual](https://www.playstation.com/manual/pdf/PS3-02_03-1.5_2.pdf/) as "HDD access indicator".